# IOS How to save and load JSON String to memory

Tags: ios, json, swift, caching, save

I am using NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() to save my JSON String got from WebService to iPhone memory. When I load it to use with my parser function, the processing speed is so slow. I don't want to use RealmIO or any database because that thing doesn't necessary. I would like to ask is there any way faster than NSUserDefaults?  [Please check my JSON file (I need store more than 20 files like that)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/311p5jtzreky8p6/document.json?dl=0)

Comment: Not JSON string, but JSON data. JSON documents are not strings. All the interfaces expect or produce NSData.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving your data to `NSUserDefaults`, you should save it to a different file, this will be much more efficient.

Here is how you can do it :

```
// Build file url
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last!
let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file_1.json", isDirectory: false)

// Write
let jsonString = "..."
let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
do {
    try jsonData?.writeToURL(fileURL, options: NSDataWritingOptions())
} catch {
    NSLog("Writing file to `\(fileURL)` failed with error : \(error)")
}

// Read
do {
    let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch {
    NSLog("Reading file at url `\(fileURL)` failed with error : \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is not a database. If your JSON documents are more than 100 KB altogether store them into separate documents. Note that every time you change *any* user default, all the user defaults have to be written to a file. If you have 20 JSON documents of 1MB each, that's writing 20MB or more for *every* user default the you change.